# Is there an informal term for the "best company in an industry"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for an informal term or an expression to define the best company (the more competitive and successful) within a specific industry.

A similar example is the expression "*killer application*"  which is often used to refer to most successful software applications. 
A formal expression I often see is "industry leader", but I need an informal or slang one.

***Sample usage:***

> IBM used to be the......of the IT industry in the past.

Comment: **top dog** would be my go-to for this.

Comment: @John Clifford Perhaps not if it's the cat-food industry.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ESPECIALLY if it's the cat food industry.

Comment: Can *top dog* be used to refer to a company? Can you provide some reference please.

Comment: @Saturana See http://www.forbes.com/sites/danschawbel/2013/02/19/po-bronson/#252417d625e0 for example.

Comment: @Saturana https://www.rt.com/uk/331158-britain-global-mercenary-industry/ supports that "top dog" can be used to refer to places or entities other than people.

Comment: @JohnClifford  - interesting, would it be a problem for you to post an answer with that material?

Comment: Not at all, I shall do so.

Comment: I'm not clear why you need references if you would be happy with a slang usage. 'Top dog' is borderline highly informal - slang.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  - because I am not a native and slang informal terms have also dictionary entries. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes; you're supposed to do reasonable research yourself on ELU. Given the term, you could look for examples online yourself. By searching for "top dog" + "company" or "top dog" + "IBM", for instance. I quickly arrived at 'Amazon remains the top dog in cloud by far'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - excuse me, I didn't know about "top dog". How could I make a research on it? I know the expression "industry leader" and I am asking for an informal equivalent expression....what's wrong with it? How can research something I don't know?

Comment: I think Edwin's point was related to you asking for references after I suggested top dog as a possibility instead of trying a search to see if it could be used that way: I don't think he was suggesting that you should have known that beforehand.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have never heard of "top dog" used like this, and my English is pretty good. I might have suggested ["top cat"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/top-cat) myself, but that  meaning is quite different from *top dog* neither of which a learner would be familiar with, and would probably never dream of making up. Slang is notoriously difficult to look up, if you don't already know what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I agree. This was in response to the further request, as the previous comment assesses. I thought that 'Given the term' made this reasonably clear. In fact, let's stop hedging, it did.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth EL&U does ask users to post references, sources, in order to support their answers. The OP's request was not unreasonable, and Clifford did provide those very things, so we can leave things at that.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A It was not an answer at that time. My real concern about this sort of question is the disproportionate acclaim obvious suggestions receive. 11 upvotes for a wrong answer ('market leader') barely different from OP's suggestion.

Comment: I have seen "dominant player" used in business settings within the past few years, but I don't know whether that continues to be a popular term (business jargon tends to change rather rapidly). For example, from a BBC News story from September 3, 2013: "Nokia was the dominant player in mobile phones for more than a decade."

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think the term you're looking for is ***market leader***.

> A market leader is a company that has the largest market share in an industry, and which can use its dominance to affect the competitive landscape and direction the market takes.

<sub>Source: Market Leader Definition | Investopedia http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/market-leader.asp#ixzz42aZkmi6a</sub>

Comment: Is "market leader"  a slang expression?

Comment: @Josh61: No, *market leader* is a very well established term, used both colloquially and and in formal writing.  [Examples in the New York Times](http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/?action=click&contentCollection&region=TopBar&WT.nav=searchWidget&module=SearchSubmit&pgtype=Homepage#/"market%20leader").

Comment: @PLL - thanks, my point is that it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Josh61: ah, I take your point.  I had thought it did, since it’s not exclusively a formal/technical expression, but is also used informally.  But looking back, since the OP explicitly says they feel *industry leader* is too formal, then I guess they will feel the same way about this.

Comment: @Josh61 - you're right, my apologies. I did not read the question properly. Should I leave it up or delete it?

Comment: @Charon let the votes decide. If it goes negative, delete it.

Comment: It seems to be doing pretty well on votes, I say leave it.

Comment: *Market leader* is pretty much the same as  *industry leader*, maybe it is more informal than I think.

Comment: It seems to be doing pretty well on votes, I say delete it. You know it's wrong: show the voters they are.

Comment: @Saturana I think what's weird about this question and what makes this answer get upvotes is that people don't often use slang when talking about companies like IBM, at least not in my experience. If someone did use slang, possibly for humorous reasons, there are so many options and variations I can't think of what would be best.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'll only back you up on that if it gets more upvotes than mine has. :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Okay, it clearly needs to go now. ;)

Comment: My instinct is that "industry leader" is closer to the inquirer's sense of *best*;  the term "market leader", as indicated here, indicates *largest*, which is not exactly the same thing.

Comment: I upvoted, and think this is the right answer. However, that definition you quoted is horrible.

Comment: Did you read the question? I even checked the edit history to be sure you were mistaken. "I am looking for an **informal** term"

Answer (score 28):

I would go with **top dog** for this. As defined by [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/top-dog)

> a person, group, or nation that has acquired a position of highest authority.

I would posit that a company can be considered a group, and therefore the term could be applied to one.

[Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/danschawbel/2013/02/19/po-bronson/#252417d625e0) and [rt.com](https://www.rt.com/uk/331158-britain-global-mercenary-industry/) support this usage of the term in contexts involving nations or companies.

"IBM used to be the top dog of the IT industry in the past" should be recognised by most native speakers as a reference to their dominance and success.

Comment: IMHO, 'used to be...in the past' sounds awful, even ungrammatical.  Are you OK with it?

Comment: @Egox As with most of the sample sentences I mirror back, I usually use the same form the OP used. I agree that it sounds awful, and should either be "IBM used to be the top dog of the IT industry" or "IBM was the top dog of the industry in the past" but I didn't want to cause confusion.

Comment: Also, "cat's meow".

Comment: @alfreema or cat's whiskers, or bees knees, or dog's bollocks...we seem to have an amusingly large stock of idioms meaning "best thing" that are body parts of animals.

Comment: @Egox - I don't think it is ungrammatical, but it certainly is redundant.

Comment: "Alpha Dog" would be a close second to "Top Dog"

Answer (score 10):

The leading example in any field is known as the [*Paragon*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+paragon).

A paragon is an example that is held to be an example of excellence.
The word is used in many fields, industry being just one of them.

Answer (score 10):

This is *not* one word, but for a common expression, I'd suggest "**(the) 800 pound gorilla** in/of ... industry."

"IBM is the 800 pound gorilla in the IT-industry."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/800-pound_gorilla

"800-pound gorilla" is an American English expression for a person or organization so powerful that it can act without regard to the rights of others or the law. The phrase is rooted in a joke riddle:

"Where does an 800-lb. gorilla sit?"

The answer:

"Anywhere it wants to."

This highlights the disparity of power between the "800-lb. gorilla" and everything else.

The term can describe a powerful geopolitical and military force, or, in business, a powerful corporate entity that has such a large majority percentage of whatever market they compete within that they can use that strength to crush would-be competitors. (The metaphor includes an inherent bit of hyperbole; the highest weight yet recorded for an actual obese gorilla is 600 lb. (270 kg). The average weight is 400 lb.)

The metaphor has been mixed, on occasion, with the metaphor of the elephant in the room.[1]

Comment: There's not necessarily even a relation between the two. Company A could produce the best products, while company B could have enough distribution muscle to dominate the industry.

Answer (score 7):

Try *cream of the crop*.

> Fig. the best of all. *This particular car is the cream of the crop. These three students are very bright. They are the cream of the crop in their class.*
>   [- The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cream+of+the+crop)

It's a little awkward in your sample sentence but here's a slight rewording:

> In the IT industry, IBM used to be the cream of the crop.

Since you're looking for colloquial usage, here are some examples from around the web:

- IBM has always been the cream of the crop. - [shakarocks](http://www.cougarboard.com/board/message.html?id=3389895)
- IBM was the cream of the crop. - [Anders Bylund](http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2009/01/22/ibm-is-dead-long-live-ibm.aspx)
- IBM was the cream of the crop, until the 75 GXP. - [Bozo](http://www.storageforum.net/forum/showthread.php/4674-New-SATA-II-hard-drive-16Mb-cache?p=68314&viewfull=1#post68314)

Comment: closely relate: [Crem de la creme](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cr%C3%A8me_de_la_cr%C3%A8me) - the best of something

Comment: Thanks @WernerCD. I saw that phrase as well but thought the words were either French or at least too raw an import into English for this site.

Comment: Well... I guess you could say that. Being American, there are more than a few phrases I'd consider common place even if they aren't purely "English". C'est La Vie as a second one. It's not like the etymology of language ain't a mixture of every other language due to our diverse immigration inputs anyways.

Answer (score 7):

1. May I suggest, the idiom **head and shoulders above** (not the anti-dandruff shampoo).
   If something or someone is *[head and shoulders above the rest](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/head-and-shoulders-above)*, it means they are by far the best in that field.

   > - In this regard IBM stands head and shoulders above the rest.
   >     Source: [The Wall Street Journal](http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2015/01/12/ibm-wins-most-patents-again-but-google-apple-climb-in-rankings/)
2. Something a little more fancy, perhaps? How about a French expression; **crème de la crème** Cambridge Dictionaries Online says: *[the ​best ​people in a ​group or the ​best ​type of a ​particular thing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/the-creme-de-la-creme)*
3. A **world-beater** suggests the best of its kind, the number one par excellence. It has  a more dynamic and modern sound than the previous two suggestions. From the BBC website, an article entitled

> [What happened to Japan's electronic giants?.](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-21992700)
>
> Mr Nakanishi decided to return Hitachi to its core business: heavy engineering. Gas turbines, steam turbines, nuclear power plants, high-speed trains, these are the areas he believes **Hitachi can still be a world beater**, especially in the developing world.

4. **Front-runner** [*the ​person, ​animal, or ​organization that is most ​likely to ​win something*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/front-runner) [CDO] From the same BBC article, the term is used to great effect

> Mr Nakanishi's strategy is working. Hitachi is back in profit. **Hitachi trains are the front-runner** in the competition to replace all of the UK's fleet of inter-city high-speed trains.

Comment: One answer per answer, please.

Comment: @MathieuK.  I'd rather not post four separate answers which are roughly synonymous. However, if the answer suggested is radically different then it's a good idea to post a separate answer. Which I have done in the past by the way. This is a problem with single-word requests, often there is more than one possible answer this encourages lists, but as long as you justify, support or  explain  each term the OP can make an informed choice.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Mmhmm, but it makes it harder to vote on. For instance, I really like your fourth one (front-runner), as it both came to mind and also probably fits--the front-runner in a marketplace or industry would necessarily be most competitive (that is, most likely to succeed). However, I'm powerless to do anything about this, as it's lumped in with other answers to which I do not wish to extend my vote.

Comment: @MathieuK. You should vote up if you've found the answer **useful** (at least most part of it), and vote down if the answer is terribly wrong. If an answer contains a list, you may mention in the comments why you think certain items aren't fitting here. If you're confused, then just don't vote at all. Entering multiple answers is discouraged if they are mostly similar.

Comment: Then I'd suggest that these four are mostly dissimilar.

Answer (score 6):

If there is an element of innovation, then **"trailblazer"** may be appropriate.

**Trailblazer** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trailblazer)

> a person who makes, does, or discovers something new and makes it acceptable or popular; a pioneer
>   *"a trailblazer in astrophysics"*

Comment: A *trailblazer* is one of the "first," not necessarily one of the "best," and it is the latter that is asked after. The Apple Lisa was a *trailblazer* in that it was the first personal computer to offer a GUI, but it was a terrible failure as a product.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of two expressions that were borrowed from other examples, and became idioms:

- [Gold Standard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gold+standard): (2nd def in link) A model of excellence; a paragon.
- [Cadillac](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Cadillac):  The name of something powerful or superior. (From the name of the automobile.)

Example usage:

- Our company is setting the gold standard in the retail landscaping products sector.
- In my opinion, the orange is the Cadillac of fruits.

The second is falling out of use as the image and reputation of that particular General Motors automobile brand is no longer as prevalent as it once was.  I still hear it used once in while, including facetiously:  The BMW is the Cadillac of automobiles.

Comment: Be careful about using brand names and/or registered trade marks like Cadillac in this way. Some companies can be quite aggressive in protecting their brand names from becoming "commonly used words," for example "hoover" used a noun or a verb referring to any activity which involves collecting items together, rather than brand name of a specific product. If such a reference is used in a publication that is widely circulated, you may get a response from the brand name's legal department.

Comment: Reminds me of "Water is nature's fruit juice."

Comment: Ironically, Cadillac once tried to use the advertising slogan "Cadillac - the Rolls Royce of cars".

Answer (score 4):

The term *[bellwether](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bellwether)*, defined in MW as

> one that takes the lead or initiative :  leader;
>
> also :  an indicator of trends

interprets *best* as being the leader. If financial
performance made a company "best", then for years
you would consider Microsoft to be the best technology
company in the world. If you use "leader", you would 
have picked IBM, then something around Microsoft/Intel/Dell,
and probably now Apple.

For e.g.: IBM used to be the **bellwether** of the IT industry in the past.

Answer (score 4):

*"IBM used to be the **king/boss/top-gun** of the IT industry"*

**King** (or queen, if preferred) — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/king)

> a person or thing preeminent in its class: *"the king of actors."*

**Boss** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boss)

> One who makes important decisions or exercises authority.

**Top Gun** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/top-gun)

> the most important or powerful person in a particular sphere; the top-ranked person in a group.

Comment: Similar to each other, but non-identical—should this be two answers?

Comment: @MathieuK. It cannot be two separate answers unless they are two completely different ones.

Comment: "King of the industry" was the first thing that popped to my mind when i read the question.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of good options here, one that I've heard before, particularly in an investment context, is *best of breed*.

From [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/best_of_breed.asp#ixzz42qYJtXfz):

> A stock that represents the most optimal investment choice for a
>   specific sector or industry due to its high quality compared to its
>   competitors. This slang is derived from dog shows, where the highest
>   quality dog for each breed wins an award and is given the "best of
>   breed" title.

There is similar (though not exactly the same) usage from [Gartner](http://www.gartner.com/it-glossary/best-of-breed), who would likely have classed IBM as such at some point.

Comment: `best in class` is the term I would apply to anything other than an animal. Google offers over 1 billion results for `best in class term`.

Comment: Best of breed is definitely widely used in the financial industry. Although sometimes I see it with hyphens: best-of-breed

Comment: @sq33g this is a figurative or slang term, best in class is the more literal or formal equivalent, definitely similar terms.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single word answer, you may consider

> Acme

Acme is defined (on [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/acme?s=t)) as:

> the highest point; summit; peak:
>   *The empire was at the acme of its power.*

Therefore the preeminent company in its field would be said to be the acme of that field. In fact, you might also want to consider preeminent. Defined at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/preeminent?s=t) as:

> eminent above or before others; superior; surpassing:
>   *He is preeminent in his profession.*

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this suggestion was downvoted without comment. Have I misread the original question or missed the point?

Comment: Not my down vote, but would you say  *"IBM used to be the acme of IT industry*"?

Comment: @Saturana: yes, I would - either that or say _"IBM were once preeminent in the IT industry"_.

Comment: Due to Loony Toons I would assume IBM used to be the acme of the IT industry would mean it was a joke.

Answer (score 2):

I go for *lodestar*.

> IBM used to be the lodestar of the IT industry in the past.

[In other words](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lodestar), IBM at one time served as a guide or model as to how things could and should be done in the IT industry. IBM set the standard but was subsequently imitated and surpassed by various Johnnies-come-lately.

Answer (score 2):

From Lewis's comment: **at the head**.

Other expressions similarly denoting elevated status:

- IBM used to be **at the top** of the IT industry.
- IBM used to be **the top company** of the IT industry.
- IBM used to be **chief** (or **head**) of the IT industry.

Comment: Also **leader**, though that's not informal: IBM used to be leader of the IT industry.

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

***big name***

> A recognized leader in a particular field.
>
> [Random House Kennerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/big+name)
>
> *Grumman Aircraft Engineering Corp., which used to be the big name in this field, has stopped making this type of plane for the commercial market, now produces only for the government.)*
>
> [Business Week](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XZsiAQAAMAAJ&q=%22used+to+be+the+big+name+in%22&dq=%22used+to+be+the+big+name+in%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3vODc77_LAhUFOJoKHcZGC78Q6AEIHTAA)

***flagship***

> : the best, largest, or most important one of a group of things (such as products, stores, etc.)
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flagship)
>
> *Photoshop used to be the flagship of this company.* [Photoshop Family](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/switching_tabs_in_wrong_order_shortcut_roundabout)
>
> *Cadillac's newest flagship was revealed tonight in New York.*
> [The Coolist](http://www.thecoolist.com/tag/cadillac/)

Comment: + 1 A usage example may be helpful.

Comment: NIce. But, is it an informal term as the OP requires?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy UrbanDictionary marks it as "slang" http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Flagship

Comment: "Flagship" is usually used for the premier location within a single company.   To indicate the top *company* within an *industry*, the word **"benchmark"** is probably more common. (US)

Comment: *Flagship* is used for a company's main, or premier, product. It is not used for company (but someone could start such a use, of course). And your examples reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

**pinnacle** might suit your usage. It's about something being the highest level, akin to a 'peak'.

> the highest or culminating point, as of success, power, fame, etc.:

For example:

> *the pinnacle of one's career.*

[Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pinnacle)

As [mbomb007](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/125966/mbomb007) points out

> pinnacle suggests that IBM was the peak, but also suggests that the IT industry as a whole has gone downhill since then, rather than that IBM is no longer the leader.

This association depends a bit on how you use it but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Using **pinnacle** suggests that IBM was the peak, but also suggests that the IT industry as a whole has gone downhill since then, rather than that IBM is no longer the leader, which probably isn't what the OP wants to convey.

Comment: Also, "apex" meaning the top of the mountain. But I don't think these are informal (enough).

Comment: @mbomb007 That's a good point I'll add in. I think it depends on usage but that's definitely an association that's involved.

Answer (score 1):

I would perhaps consider 'Forerunner';

> a person or thing that precedes the coming or development of someone
>   or something else. "the ice safe was a forerunner of today's
>   refrigerator" synonyms:   predecessor, precursor, antecedent, ancestor,
>   forebear;

*IBM used to be the **forerunner** of the IT industry in the past.*

Comment: Thanks,  but forerunners are not always the best in the industry.

Comment: @Saturana I, on a personal level, would disagree with that. Forerunner is usually synonymous  with Forefront, which is generally used to describe a person or a company at the head of their respective field. But point taken.

Comment: A forerunner is often "first" but not "best", so it can often be confusing. Literally "one who came before". Being first chronologically does not necessarily imply the best in the industry, e.g. "Pets.com is a forerunner of today's modern online storefronts".

Comment: If you replace _forerunner_ with  _predecessor_, _precursor_, _antecedent_, _ancestor_, or _forebear_ in the example sentence, you'll see that the resulting sentence does not convey the notion of "best company in the industry"—and that it tends to be even more redundant than it was when "used to be ... in the past" was the only repetition. For example: "IBM used to be the ancestor of the IT industry in the past."  It doesn't work logically either: It used to be the ancestor but now it's not?

Comment: "archaic: an advance messenger." –Google. You *are* the best in the industry if you are the only one in it. IMO, (yes, there were others) IBM single-handedly heralded the computer age. IBM *was* the forerunner, but it is no longer at the forefront. Either way, the colloquial use of this word fits the OP's requirement of it being slang.

Answer (score 1):

In a review of the top five on-line tax preparation services, Yardena Arar of PCWorld declares in the review’s title that “TurboTax Is Still **[the One to Beat](http://www.pcworld.com/article/250132/tax_sites_turbotax_is_still_the_one_to_beat.html)**” and later, early in paragraph 3, uses the more formal “market-leading TurboTax” to reiterate the title’s declaration.

There’s also a similar and relevant use of “[still] [the one to beat](http://blogs.ft.com/beyond-brics/2011/06/09/indian-it-ibm-still-the-one-to-beat/)” in the title of a blog entry discussing how IBM, the very company mentioned in your example sentence is [still] a “market leader” in India.
(from Akanksha Awal’s blog, ‘beyondbrics’)